# Application like Windows Task Manager

Tags: software-recommendation, monitor, system, task-management

Is there any program like Task Manager for Windows which can kill any full screen program (mostly Windows games I play through wine) when it got stuck and it don't want anything to come above it?

I know Htop and system monitor are great in their own way but is there anything can go on top like Windows Task Manager?

Comment: Try setting a keyboard shortcut for the command `xkill` which will invoke a "killer cursor".

Comment: See here http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/10-best-linux-task-managers

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

If you are using in GUI environment you can use lxtask:

```
apt-get install lxtask
```

Comment: It seems OP is aware of this: "I know Htop and system monitor are great in their own way but is there anything can go on top like Windows Task Manager?"

Comment: thanks, but you are telling me same thing in light package , i want a program that can go above any full screen locked program(stuck/not working but still in fullscreen) and kill it .